# I cannot get the app to construct an sqlite database

Tags: java, android-sqlite

Hello as the title says I cannot get the app to construct a small local sqlite database. I would appreciate some help as I m an amateur. Thanks in advance.
Below there are some pictures of my source code.

I tested this code on level 24 API device, but the database does not appear in the data/data/the_package/databases/ folder

**Edited** to include code

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CrdDBHelper mydb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mydb = new CrdDBHelper(this);

        boolean p1 = true;
        int p11sc = 0;
        int p12sc = 0;
        Button btnMenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMenu);
        Button btntrue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTrue);
        Button btnFalse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFalse);

        // All other available code commented out
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mydb.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**CrdDBContract.java**

```
public final class CrdDBContract {

    private CrdDBContract(){}

    public static final class GameEntry implements BaseColumns {

        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Game";
        public static final String COLUMN_KNOWN = "Known";
        public static final String COLUMN_TBF = "TBF";
        public static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                        + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                        + COLUMN_KNOWN + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                        + COLUMN_TBF + " TEXT NOT NULL)";
    }
}
```

**CrdDBHelper.java**

```
public class CrdDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CardGame.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public CrdDBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CrdDBContract.GameEntry.SQL_CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

**CrdDBDataInsertion.java**

```
public class CrdDBDataInsertion {

    //??????????? Code not available from images
    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    private void contentvalues(String Known, String TBF) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CrdDBContract.GameEntry.COLUMN_KNOWN,Known);
        values.put(CrdDBContract.GameEntry.COLUMN_TBF,TBF);
        long newid =  mDB.insert(CrdDBContract.GameEntry.TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    }
}
```

[Main Activity part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK9We.png)[Main Activity part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y1wc.png)
[Main Activity part3(final)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5zZG.png)

[DB Contract class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZrFj.png)

[DB Helper class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaIfv.png)

[DB insert class part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsGgQ.png)

[DB insert class part2 (final)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufBzV.png)

Comment: just a suggestion.. try to paste your code rather than posting images, most people like to work along your solution and would not prefer to write the code from scratch

Comment: Your issue is that no attempt is made to actually open the database, (just instantiating the **CrdDBHelper** object doesn't attempt to open the database). It is not until an attempt is made to access (open) the database that the **onCreate** method is called (and this is the only time it is called) and the databse is created. You can force this in the **CrdDBHelper** constructor by calling **getWritableDatabase**  e.g. by adding the line **`getWritableDatabase();`** after the super call in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't, according to the code, acessing(opening) the database. You are just instantiating the DatabseHelper in **MainActivity** i.e. `mydb = new CrdDBHelper(this);`

It is not until an attempt is made to open the database (which is frequently implicit) that the database is actually created.

A simple way would be to force an open when instantiating the database. e.g. call the getWritableDatabase() method in the constructor, like :-

```
public CrdDBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    getWritableDatabase();
}
```

Perhaps at that time set an SQLiteDatabase object with the returned SQLiteDatabase, so your Database Helper (**CrdDBHelper.java**) could be :-

```
public class CrdDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CardGame.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

   SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public CrdDBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mDB = this.getWriteableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CrdDBContract.GameEntry.SQL_CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

- as the **onCreate** method is called when (and ONLY when) the database is created the Game table will then be created.